# Windows 8 won't boot from GRUB menu, have to change UEFI settings for Windows to boot

Tags: windows

Hello SuperUser community,

I recently decided to dual-boot Lubuntu and Windows 8 on my computer (pre-installed with Windows 8) to learn more about how dual-booting and partitioning work. The process went pretty smoothly, with one minor issue:

On the GRUB menu, whenever I select "Windows Boot Manager", it gives me the following error:

```
/EndEntire
file path: /ACPI(a0341d0,0)/PCI(2,1f)/Sata(0,0,0)/HD(2,1f4800,82000,f5f79a8387ee5a48,2,2/File(\EFI
\Microsoft\Boot)/File(bootmgfw.efi)/EndEntire error: cannot load image.

Press any key to continue... _
```

I am still able to boot to Windows 8. As mentioned [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/280339/windows-8-wont-boot-via-grub-after-intalling-12-10-with-boot-repair), all I have to do is go into the UEFI settings and move Windows Boot Manager up to the first boot priority, plus run Boot Repair in Lubuntu and restore EFI backups. However, after I do that, I don't get the GRUB menu upon restarting. I'm taken directly to Windows 8 without any boot menu or choice between Windows and Lubuntu. If I want to boot Lubuntu, I've got to change the boot priority for that again.

So my question is: how can I resolve the above error, so that I can choose between Windows and Lubuntu in the GRUB menu without having to change the boot settings in the UEFI? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh well, I figured out the solution to my own question. I'm able to boot both Lubuntu and Windows from GRUB now. The issue was that I THOUGHT Secure Boot was disabled, when it really wasn't!

For anyone who has a Lenovo G500 laptop like me, take a look at this post on the Lenovo forums. There are TWO options for disabling Secure Boot in this brand of laptop, and unless you select "Disabled" for both options, Secure Boot will not be turned off. This is how it would look:

**Secure Boot Disabled (this is fine)**

**Secure Boot Status Enabled (you cannot change this option; it's grayed out. Until you change it, Secure Boot won't be disabled)**

To completely disable Secure Boot on your Lenovo G500 (or other laptop if it has a similar configuration), you must click on the option "Reset to setup mode" underneath the "Secure Boot Status" option. Hit "Yes" on the confirmation popup. Now, the "Secure Boot Status" will show up as "Custom". That means, Secure Boot is completely turned off (provided the above "Secure Boot" option displays Disabled). If you ever want to turn Secure Boot on again, click on "Restore factory keys".

Hopefully this helps someone who has the same problem I did. Chances are, your laptop has a confusing Secure Boot configuration and you just didn't turn it off properly.